# Ruby on Rails switching locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have very strange problem with locale switching in my application. I write simple locale switcher that store locale in sessions. It looks like this:

```
class LocalesController < ApplicationController 
  skip_authorization_check

  def switch
    session[:locale] = params[:locale]               
    redirect_to_back_or_default
  end

  private
  def redirect_to_back_or_default(default = partners_root_path)
    if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].present? and request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] != request.env["REQUEST_URI"]
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to default
    end
  end
end
```

in application_controller.rb:

```
  before_filter :set_locale 
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale =  session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
```

at the top of my routes I have;

```
get 'locales/:locale', to: "locales#switch", as: :locales
```

in my application.rb i have:

```
#config.i18n.default_locale = 'pl' I must comment this line to switcher works..
I18n.locale = 'pl'
```

and my links to language change:

```
 %a.lang-pl{href: locales_path('pl')}
 %a.lang-en{href: locales_path('en')}
```

This switcher works but not in 100% percent. When i switch language most of my breadcrumbs are not working. I change language to Polish and my app is looking for breadcrumbs translation in English file... It's very strange and I can't solve this problem. For example my breadcrumbs in ReservationsController looks like this:

```
add_breadcrumb ->(controller){controller.current_partner.rental_company.name}, :partners_root_path
add_breadcrumb I18n.t('reservations.reservations'), :planned_partners_reservations_path
add_breadcrumb t('reservations.reservation.list_planned'
```

For creating breadcrumbs I use breadcrumbs_on_rails gem. I attach screenshot what's wrong when I switch to Polish langugage(first and last breadcrumb is ok but second is not). Please help.

[image]

Edit:
I found that problem casuses:

```
I18n.t('reservations.reservations')
```

This I18n.t casues problem. When I change it to:
`t('reservations.reservations')` and replace to index action it works like charm.
Now the problem is how can I change this I18n to something else?

Edit:
My controller looks like this:

```
 class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
   add_breadcrumb ->(controller){controller.current_partner.rental_company.name}, :partners_root_path
    add_breadcrumb I18n.t('partners.employees.home'), :partners_employees_path

    def index
      add_breadcrumb t('partners.employees.list')
      @employees = @employees.order("partners.last_name ASC")
    end
end
```

This structure of my breadcrumbs. This I18n.t breadcrubms causes the problem. When I change I18n.t to: t and place it in index action everything is fine. Now the question is how to do to breadcrumbs with this I18n works...

Comment: show your pl.yml locale file.

Comment: Thx for reply, I've updated the post. The problem is with this I18n.t in controller. Maybe you know the solution for this strange thing?

Comment: glad you figured it out but now what do you mean by- "Now the problem is how can I change this I18n to something else?" 1. what do you mean by something else 2. there are several i18n in the code which one you want to change and why?

Comment: I've updated post. Look what my controller looks like and maybe you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `t` helper is just an alias of the `I18n.translate` method, made available by Rails' `ActionPack` in your controllers and views. In models you still need to use the full thing: `I18n.t`.

Other than that it should not matter which variant you use. If it makes a difference it means that something is overwriting the `t` helper.

The `translation_missing:en.reservations.reservations` means that everything works as expected but you have not provided an actual translation for the specific key in this locale (`en`). To do that you need to go to `config/locales/en.yml` and edit it as:

```
en:
  reservations:
    reservations: Your translation here..
```

I suggest you go through the [Rails I18n Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) once more.

Comment: The right translations are not there in the non-english context so the structure you specified should be in pl.yml file and not en.yml I guess.

Comment: But in the screenshot the OP provided it clearly has stuff listed in Polish and Rails complains for `en.reservations...`. This means he is using the English locale and he has missing and polish translations for that.